# Moment gives me invalid date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Consider the following:

```
console.log(moment(investment.updated_at.date, 'MMDDYYYY'));
```

This gives me a Moment Object back:

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2015-10-27 10:22:22", _f: "MMDDYYYY", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object…}
```

When I call:

```
console.log(moment(investment.updated_at.date, 'MMDDYYYY').fromNow());
```

I get invalid date error: `Invalid date`

Any idea as to how this isn't formatting properly? the date being passed to moment is:  `2015-10-27 10:22:22`

Comment: Can you share the precise value of `investment.updated_at.date`?

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: Try `console.log(moment.utc(moment(investment.updated_at.date, 'MMDDYYYY'))..fromNow());`

Comment: @zerkms No need to be rude ..

Comment: @tyleha and I don't agree

Comment: @developerbmw it assumes that OP understood that the second value being passed to moment was a format string with which to interpret the first. Obviously, OP did not know that, which is why he came here and asked the question. zerkms's comment felt a bit rude to my tastes, but I'll allow that others can interpret it differently. to each his own.

Comment: ^ This is the problem with SO. People copy and paste code rather than reading the documentation.

Comment: @developerbmw a very fair point.

Comment: @KyleAdams zerkms gave you a helpful pointer in the right direction. You called him a "dick". Sorry but who is being "rude" here? Also, I checked the moment docs. They are very clear on the format string and provide a nice table of all the different options. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are specifying a format that does not match your actual date string when creating the moment object. `MMDDYYYY` would only match dates that looked like `10272015`.

Instead, let moment do its thing - it's familiar with the format of a string `2015-10-27 10:22:22`.

```
moment(investment.updated_at.date).fromNow();
```

If you wanna be really specific about it for some reason you can pass moment the format string `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'` which matches your data.

Comment: You need to be very careful with that. `2015-10-27 10:22:22` will be parsed based on the time zone of the host system settings, so will produce a different value in systems with different settings.

Comment: Terrific point. Datetimes are not very useful without timezone. Depends on the use case, but if you want normalization you can lean on UTC with `moment.utc(date)`

Comment: This led me to my solution in a roundabout way. It made me realise you have to format the date with hyphens rather than forward slashes.